# Android UsbManager on API level 1

Tags: android, usb

How can I use UsbManager class in Android API level 1? I'll try the code below but I can not reach UsbManager.

```
IntentFilter deviceAttachedFilter = new IntentFilter();
deviceAttachedFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
deviceAttachedFilter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, deviceAttachedFilter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html), UsbManager was introduced with API level 12.

There is no way to use it on previous platform versions. It runs as a system service, and those cannot be easily backported.